# Display form fields depending on DropDownList selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When a user selects an Asset Type, i want my "Create" form to display different fields depending on the Asset Type selected.

For example: if a user selects Asset Type "Laptop", i want the form to display all the relevant fields for a Laptop Asset. However, if a user selects Asset Type "Printer", i want the form to display relevant fields for a Printer Asset.

Here is my Asset Model:

```
public class Asset
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public int AssetMakeID { get; set; }
    public int AssetTypeID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string AssetModel { get; set; }
    public string AssetSerialNo { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string WarrantyInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePurchased { get; set; }
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public int CPUID { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string HardDrive { get; set; }
    public int OperatingSystemID { get; set; }
    public string OperatingSystemProductKey { get; set; }
```

Obviously, not all these attributes apply to a Printer Asset.

Here is my Create method in my Asset Controller:

```
 // GET: Asset/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.AssetMakeID = new SelectList(db.AssetMake, "AssetMakeID", "Name");
            ViewBag.AssetTypeID = new SelectList(db.AssetType, "AssetTypeID", "Type");
            ViewBag.CPUID = new SelectList(db.CPU, "CPUID", "Name");
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Department, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
            ViewBag.OperatingSystemID = new SelectList(db.OperatingSyst, "OperatingSystemID", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Asset/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AssetID,AssetMakeID,AssetTypeID,User,DepartmentID,AssetModel,AssetSerialNo,PurchaseOrderNo,Supplier,WarrantyInfo,DatePurchased,ComputerName,CPUID,RAM,HardDrive,OperatingSystemID,OperatingSystemProductKey")] Asset asset)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Asset.Add(asset);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.AssetMakeID = new SelectList(db.AssetMake, "AssetMakeID", "Name", asset.AssetMakeID);
            ViewBag.AssetTypeID = new SelectList(db.AssetType, "AssetTypeID", "Type", asset.AssetTypeID);
            ViewBag.CPUID = new SelectList(db.CPU, "CPUID", "Name", asset.CPUID);
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Department, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName", asset.DepartmentID);
            ViewBag.OperatingSystemID = new SelectList(db.OperatingSyst, "OperatingSystemID", "Name", asset.OperatingSystemID);
            return View(asset);
        }
```

How would i go about displaying fields in my Create View depending on the AssetTypeID a user selects?

Comment: The first solution that comes to my mind is to return a view/partial view per asset Id.
Create a Dictionary or a database table to hold the relation AssetId-View/Partial View.